# Angular 4 Directive selector to target an element inside a component only

Tags: angular, selector, directive

How to target a specific element inside a component in Angular Directive.
I have a component with selector "highlighter".  This component has content project using ng-content. 
There is a directive with selector "highlighter input". 
I believe this directive should get applied to any input only inside the highlighter component only but it gets applied to all the inputs in the application - whats wrong?

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/4zd31C?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'highlighter',
  template: `
    This should be highlighted: 
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class HighlighterComponent {
}

@Directive({
  selector: 'highlighter input'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Selectors in Angular don't support [combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators):

```
- descendant selector (space)
- child selector (>)
- adjacent sibling selector (+)
- general sibling selector (~)
```

So the last distinct selector in the string wins, which is `input` in your case. That's why it's applied to all inputs.

Another thing is that projected content is not considered to be located inside a component to which is projected. So even if Angular supported combinator selectors, the selector `highlighter input` still shouldn't work.

The simplest solution would be to add a class to the input like this:

```
<input class="highlighter">
```

and target this class in the selector:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input.highlighter'
```

Comment: I made a page where you can test how your directive selector is parsed by angular compiler, that's really weird : https://ydomenjoud.github.io/angular-selector-parser/

Answer (score 2):

[One clue that I found in the Angular doc](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#metadata-properties) is that:

> Angular only allows directives to trigger on CSS selectors that do not cross element boundaries.

Comment: meaning what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Directives will be applied to all selectors within the module it is declared.

Comment: directives should be applied based on directive selector!   How is selector read in this case?

Comment: Lol. Directive can not be applied to a selector. What it even means to apply a directive to selector? :D